# Displaying counts and tables based on external files

Tags: tables, include, import, external

I've got a complex report that I'm trying to generate, and I'm at a loss on how best to get it working. Let me say that using CSV files is not an option, for starters.

I have a number of files named like `inc/long-name.tex` and `inc/longer-name.tex` which each define entire subsections with figures, tables, you name it. Changing the names of the files to be numbered and using counting loops is not desirable. I wish to import these files near the bottom of the main document using a hypothetical macro `\customimport{category}{status}{long-name}`.

In many places through the document, both above and below where the sections should appear, I need to be able to generate counts and tables of the imported subsections based on their categories and displaying their names. For instance, I have one paragraph that needs to say:

> There were `\categoryfoonum` instances of category foo, `\categorybarnum` instances of category bar, and `\categorybaznum` instances of category bax.

And at another place, I require a table that includes hyper-linked references, names, and categories for the subsections that appear in the order in which `\customimport` was called. For example, the table would look similar to:

```
|---------+-----------------------+----------+--------|
| Number  | Name                  | Category | Status |
|---------+-----------------------+----------+--------|
| Counter | Linked Name of Foo  1 | Foo      | Status |
| Counter | Linked Name of Foo  2 | Foo      | Status |
| Counter | Linked Name of Bar  1 | Bar      | Status |
| Counter | Linked Name of Baz  1 | Baz      | Status |
|---------+-----------------------+----------+--------|
```

What is the nicest way to accomplish this?

**EDIT: Sample Code **

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inc/long-name.tex}
  \begin{incsection}{This name is from the file}
    \par{Explanation}
    This contains many tables and figures.
  \end{incsection}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inc/longer-name.tex}
  \begin{incsection}{This name is from the other file}
    \par{Explanation}
    This contains many tables and figures.
  \end{incsection}
\end{filecontents}

% Many more files will be in the inc directory...

\newenvironment{incsection}[1]{
  % #1 needs to be available when creating the table and needs to be hyperref'd.
  % Many other formatting commands here.
}{
  % Many other formatting commands here.
}

\begin{document}

% Create category counters.
\newcounter{incnum}
\newcounter{categoryfoonum}
\newcounter{categorybarnum}
\newcounter{categorybaznum}

\newcommand{customimport}[3]{
  % Remember how many things we're including.
  \stepcounter{incnum}
  % Remember how many of each category we're including.
  \stepcounter{category#1num}
  % This line breaks the example, not sure what to do instead.
  \input{inc/#3}
}

% These numbers are used before \customimport is called.
\par There were \thecategoryfoonum instances of category foo, \thecategorybarnum
instances of category bar, and \thecategorybaznum instances of category baz.

% This table needs all rows to be dynamically generated, and needs to appear
% before \customimport is called.
\newcounter{rownum}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | l | c | c | }
  \hline
  Number & Name & Category & Status\\
  \hline
  % These lines need to be replaced...
  S.\therownum\stepcounter{rownum} & This name is from the file       & foo & status1 \\
  S.\therownum\stepcounter{rownum} & This name is from the other file & bar & status2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{Foos}
\customimport{foo}{status1}{long-name}
% More foo files here...

\subsection*{Bars}
\customimport{bar}{status2}{longer-name}
% More bar files here...

\subsection*{Bazs}
% No baz files in this document instance...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered without the slightest information about the code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I take your point. I'll work up a skeleton to try and explain it more.

Comment: `\par` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Note that this really doesn't have anything to do with the use of external files. It makes no difference that parts of the document are in other files. You could put them in place in the document and the question would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that probably your question should be split into more manageable parts. The code below should be regarded as probably not the way to do it on the grounds that I'm using the TeX Book's index to look bits up, which probably isn't the best way to figure this stuff out.

## *Caveat emptor...*

---

If you need to access the value of a counter or other information before it is specified in the document, then you must write that information to an external file and read it back on the next run. You cannot access it in real-time because the page on which the information is required may be typeset before the information is available (unless the information is available before the page on which it is required is shipped out, which seems unlikely here).

Therefore, you cannot use `\thecountername` to access the total value of the counter at the end of the document *and* use `countername` to count something in the document. You could create separate counters, but there is not much point. It is more straightforward to just create a macro to hold the total count at document end.

To ensure we don't get errors on the first run:

```
\let\totalbars\relax
\let\totalfoos\relax
\let\totalbazs\relax
```

On the first run, nothing will be typeset when these commands are called.

Then, at the end of the document, we write the value of the relevant counters to the `.aux` file, saving it into the relevant macro:

```
\AtEndDocument{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\gdef\string\totalbars{\thecategorybarnum}%
    \string\gdef\string\totalfoos{\thecategoryfoonum}%
    \string\gdef\string\totalbazs{\thecategorybaznum}%
  }%
}
```

The easiest way to deal with the table is probably to write the rows to a dedicated external file, in the same way that the table of contents is written to `.toc` etc.

The following assumes that all the relevant files are fed in only after the table is typeset. This simplifies things (at least conceptually for me) so, since that's what you said, I worked on that assumption.

Then `\cattoc` will typeset the table:

```
\newcommand\cattoc{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c l c c }
      \toprule
      Number & Name & Category & Status\\
      \midrule
      \input \jobname.cat
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \newwrite\writecattoc
    \immediate\openout\writecattoc=\jobname.cat
  \end{center}
}
```

This reads in the contents of `\jobname.cat` as part of the table and then opens a stream which will be written into that file at the end of the document as part of `\AtEndDocument{}`:

```
  \closeout\writecattoc
```

Then `\incsection` needs to write the relevant lines of the table to the file:

```
\newenvironment{incsection}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\writecattoc{%
    S.\string\therownum\string\stepcounter{rownum} & #1 & \csname currentcategory\endcsname & \csname currentstatus\endcsname \string\\
  }
}{%
}
```

where `\currentcategory` and `\currentstatus` reflect values to be set by the custom input command:

```
\let\currentcategory\relax
\let\currentstatus\relax

\newcommand\customimport[3]{%
  \stepcounter{incnum}%
  \expandafter\stepcounter{category#1num}%
  \gdef\currentcategory{#1}%
  \gdef\currentstatus{#2}%
  \input{#3}%
}
```

I'm not sure what `incnum` is for as it never seems to be used. But I left it here in case you have some existing use for it.

Then the output looks something like this on, of course, the second compilation:

[image: category table]

Hyperref linkage is left as an exercise for the reader or as a topic for a future question.

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{long-name.tex}
  \begin{incsection}{This name is from the file}
    Explanation\par
    This contains many tables and figures.
  \end{incsection}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{longer-name.tex}
  \begin{incsection}{This name is from the other file}
    Explanation\par
    This contains many tables and figures.
  \end{incsection}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newenvironment{incsection}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\writecattoc{%
    S.\string\therownum\string\stepcounter{rownum} & #1 & \csname currentcategory\endcsname & \csname currentstatus\endcsname \string\\
  }
}{%
}

% Create category counters.
\newcounter{incnum}
\newcounter{categoryfoonum}
\newcounter{categorybarnum}
\newcounter{categorybaznum}
\newcounter{rownum}
\let\totalbars\relax
\let\totalfoos\relax
\let\totalbazs\relax
\let\currentcategory\relax
\let\currentstatus\relax

\newcommand\customimport[3]{%
  \stepcounter{incnum}%
  \expandafter\stepcounter{category#1num}%
  \gdef\currentcategory{#1}%
  \gdef\currentstatus{#2}%
  \input{#3}%
}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\gdef\string\totalbars{\thecategorybarnum}%
    \string\gdef\string\totalfoos{\thecategoryfoonum}%
    \string\gdef\string\totalbazs{\thecategorybaznum}%
  }%
  \closeout\writecattoc
}
\newcommand\cattoc{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c l c c }
      \toprule
      Number & Name & Category & Status\\
      \midrule
      \input \jobname.cat
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \newwrite\writecattoc
    \immediate\openout\writecattoc=\jobname.cat
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

There were \totalfoos{} instances of category foo, \totalbars{} instances of category bar, and \totalbazs{} instances of category baz.

\cattoc

\subsection*{Foos}
\customimport{foo}{status1}{long-name}

\subsection*{Bars}
\customimport{bar}{status2}{longer-name}

\subsection*{Bazs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this combination of using the .aux file for the counters and using an external file for the table contents was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MakKolybabi Thanks for letting me know. I have successfully written to external files before, but I've never managed to read back from a non-standard file, so I was pleased that reading the `.cat` back seemed to work ;).